# combo box value not returning

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Below is my php file , there is a combobox with multiple options, on selection new menu should appear according to selection

All the code is in single php file that is index.php

I don't want to refresh the page or submit the value it should be done on selection/click

My url look like this

```
http://localhost/lms/grade/report/userdef/index.php?id=13
```

and in computer file is located at

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\lms\grade\report\userdef
```

it's just for clarification because jQuery need paths and stuff that I am not good with

This is my code for combo boxes and selection

```
<?php
$change;
if( isset($_GET['combo_1']) )
{
echo $change = $_GET['combo_1'];
}

echo '<select name="combo" id="combo_1">';
echo '<option value="2">Submative</option>';
echo '<option value="1">formative</option>';
echo '<option value="3">successive</option>';
echo '</select>';
 ?>
<br>
<?php
 if ($change==='1' or $change==='2')
{
$quizzes....// query for quezzes one
echo '<select id="combo_2">';
echo '<option value=" " selected="selected">Choose....</option>';
}
foreach($quizzes as $id2 => $name) {
     echo '<option value=' . $id2 . '>' . $name . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
   }

if ($change==='2')
{
quizzes2//query for quizes
echo '<select id="combo_3">';
echo '<option value=" " selected="selected">Choose....</option>';

foreach($quizzes2 as $id3 => $name2) {
     echo '<option value=' . $id3 . '>' . $name2 . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
}

if ($change==='3')
{
// another menu
}
//////more functionality
```

I am trying to return value selected using following javascript but nothing happens, its not returning the value

All the code is in single file that is `index.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#combo_1').change(function(){
        var combo_1 = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'index.php',
                data: {'combo_1':combo_1},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data)
                }
            });
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you echo a combobox??? can you placed it at the html file instead of echoing the combobox?? just a question!

Comment: to test what is being returned actually try going to this url in the browser: `http://localhost/lms/grade/report/userdef/index.php?id=13`. Its the best way to see if your `index.php` is returning the correct output.

Comment: its not thats why i asked the question 
its not returning the value
@shaikibrahim just cuz changing tag between coding is troublesome and this is just a part of file

Comment: I think its because the results has no where to echo to?? See you are calling the file to do something. It the same as you ordered food but the waiter does not know which table you are at. Something like that. That my theory . Look at w3schools for more info

Comment: 4th line, i am echoing it 
and using it aswell

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code:

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
$comboBoxval = '';
// Check Ajax Request
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // If combo_1 exist
    if (isset($_GET['DDBV'])) {
       // simple
       echo $comboBoxval = $_GET['DDBV'];
       exit;
    }    
}
?>
```

**Java Script Code:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#combo_1').change(function(){
        var DDBV = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'test.php',
                data: {'DDBV':DDBV},
                success: function(data){
                    // show ajax output to next                 
                    //$('#combo_1').after(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
    });

});
</script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<select name="combo" id="combo_1">
    <option value="2">Submative</option>
    <option value="1">formative</option>
    <option value="3">successive</option>
</select>
```

Now you will get your combo box value in ajax response

Comment: not working :S cant i put something in url: that will post  it to current page like self() or something  cuz i think i am giving a wrong url or i have to give complete url ?
my url look like this
http://localhost/lms/grade/report/userdef/index.php?id=13&quizid=63

Comment: @stacymalina: Tell me one thing first, what r u trying to achieve. DD Box Selected value or something else and what is the use of url param here if u are sending only DD Box value..?

Comment: well here is a simple explanation
i have a combobox that have different type of reports 
on selection of report type , it should open new combo box or boxes and text fields to set parameters and then i will just click show report to show specific report
i dont want to refresh page on report type selection rather i want to put its result in if condition to open a specific block

Comment: okay lets just put it in more simple way i just want to get the combo box value in a variable to use without refreshing or clicking any buttom

Comment: Okay, means you are trying to append report_type = DDBoxValue in your url, then you will get your report by report_type 1 or 2 or 3 .. right. Finally your url would be 'http://localhost/lms/grade/report/userdef/index.php?id=13&quizid=63&report_type=comboBoxvalue'

Comment: Yes!, you can do this by above code. Just assign your php var with $_GET['combo_1']; like '$change = $_GET['combo_1'];' inside '// Check Ajax Request' block.